# libpcap network traffic interception

Tags: linux, networking, pcap, libpcap

I want to intercept network traffic from user space , so I have used libpcap API s to capture tcp/ip packets . Right now I am just capturing information about the packet header & payload in the registered callback . How can I use this callback to block traffic or drop a packet based on certain conditions ? Or is pcap mechanism is purely a capture mechanism ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. As you said in your own question `libpcap` can only be used to inspect traffic passing through a network interface, it can't be used to affect this traffic in any way.

Comment: I.e., it *is* purely a capture mechanism.  (Well, later releases also support packet injection, but it does *not* support intercepting packets in the middle of the networking stack and changing them or dropping them.)

Comment: then what other library API can i use where i can not only inspect the traffic but also pass a verdict on it based on some business logic . I dont want to use a kernel module , want to achieve this using a user space component . Is using libnetfilter a good option ?